# How stream buffer is implemented in C?

Tags: c, io

I'm new to C, sorry if my question is dumb.

Where is the source code for IO stream? I want to see how the stream buffer is implemented, I can only see `_IO_FILE` struct in `libc.h`, but I don't see any internal buffer in this struct. Can anyone show me how can I locate the implmentation of stream buffer?

Comment: it's in libc but depending on what libc you use, it's possible to be written in assembler and anyway it's difficult to understand its details.

Comment: Why do you even want to know? Do you have struggle using it? This question seems like  a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/600226) to me.

Comment: The question is not dumb. Google "source code fopen" and you should find the source code of some implementations. But it's not easy to understand. But believe me, if you're new to C, you don't want to know how that works, and you don't need to know. Start with easier stuff.

Comment: This a perfectly reasonable question, and anybody's who's had to emulated C buffered I/O in an embedded system without a C library will have had to tackle it. Unfortunately, as has already been remarked, well-established implementations are pretty hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the source code for IO stream?

For glibc the code is in [`libio` directory](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=libio;hb=HEAD).

In particular, [`_IO_new_file_fopen` function](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/fileops.c;hb=3102e28bd11ed1083d3defdfd75e6d1273ab45f9#l212) implements `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

The [musl](https://musl.libc.org/) C library is very clean and well-designed.

The implementation is in the [`stdio`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio) directory, and the `stdio` internal function prototypes and macros are found in: [`stdio_impl.h`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/stdio_impl.h)